# php XML and hash/associate arrays

Tags: php, simplexml

Using PHP's SimpleXML i would like to get the key and child of an element. The first element if there are more then one. How do i do this? the 2nd line doesnt make sense so how would get the first key/val of the first element?

```
$body = $xml->Body;
$xml->Body->children() as $XX=>$ZZ;
echo "x $XX $ZZ\n";
foreach($xml->Body->children() as $k=>$v){
    echo "$k $v\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done via [IteratorIterator](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoriterator.php).
Or (even simpler) by treating the return value of children() (almost) like an array:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<foo><Body>
  <a>001</a>
  <b>002</b>
  <c>003</c>
</Body></foo>');

$c = $xml->Body->children();
if ( isset($c[0]) ) {
  echo $c->getName(), " : ", (string)$c;
}
```